# Grep a large number of commands, in rows, with colour

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Looking for some information with regards to using grep to find a large number of different strings, adding a colour.

For example;

> grep -h -i "changing" /var/log/messages*

How would I complete this output, adding a colour to any "changing" output?

Also, if I wanted to add another string "changing and battery for example" how would I colour coordinate them?

Please and thanks

Comment: What colour are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The only colouring grep can do is to highlight the found search text.

You can detect multiple things by using `grep -E 'thing1|thing2|thing3'`

If you want to print all the file but hilight the things, then you need to add a dummy match for the other lines: `grep -E '^|thing1|thing2|thing3'`.

If you want to do cleverer colouring, then sed or awk will let you inject specific colour control sequences, though you would have to hardwire it to your particular terminal type.